# Angular ControlValueAccessor detect parent validator changes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor, angular16, angular-controlvalueaccessor

When implementing a `ControlValueAccessor` I need to dynamically display some content based on whether or not the control is required.  I know I can do this to get the control:

```js
readonly #control = inject(NgControl, {self: true})
protected parentRequires = false

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.#control.valueAccessor = this

  this.parentRequires = this.#control.control?.hasValidator(Validators.required) ?? false
}
```

but that only checks to see if it's *currently* required. What I am not seeing though is how to detect changes. The parent is going to toggle the required attribute on/off based on other actions in the application.

I'm looking for something like the non-existent `this.#control.control.validatorChanges`

Comment: what if you turned it into a getter `get parentRequires(){ ... }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try that, but the idea is that Angular will trigger full validation when input validators are modified. So you can implement `Validator` directly in your `ControlValueAccessor` (yes, it can be done) just to have sort of callback when validation fires and check `this.#control.control?.hasValidator(Validators.required)` there.